# Login Page PageRequestManagerServerErrorException on ASP.NET The status code returned from the server was: 0

Tags: asp.net, error-handling, updatepanel, ajaxcontroltoolkit

We are getting strange error with our login page. It is working on almost all client but one of the client has following exception:-

When we press login button, it goes in wait mode ( in IE as well as Chrome)

When we used fiddler, it shows no response and at last it shows Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: An unknown error occurred while processing the request on the server. The status code returned from the server was: 0  in Console panel.

The login box is wraped in Update Panel that again wrapped in Script manager.

Can anybody guess whats exact issue or how do we find it.

Comment: I hope it will help you. http://weblogs.asp.net/leftslipper/archive/2007/02/26/sys-webforms-pagerequestmanagerparsererrorexception-what-it-is-and-how-to-avoid-it.aspx

Comment: I have tried this. But our problem is, it works on all the client and one single client has such issues. Can it be some updates issues in OS  with server. just guessing..